# Starting the 5.5kva Kipor diesel generator from a distance

Tags: relay

How can I start my kipor 5.5kva diesel engine generator from a distance of about 30m? I would like to avoid going outside my house to access the ignition key panel but just start from the comfort of my house.

Comment: Commerical generators have accessory panels that can do this. In your case I suspect that you will actually need to install a bypass switch and a run of cable. If done correctly, if will do electrically the same thing as turning the key.

Comment: I have tried that but theere are voltage drops along the cable.

Comment: Very long pull cord?

Answer (score 2):

If all you need to do is close a switch contact then install a suitably rated relay at the generator and operate it via a suitable voltage source and wiring.

The power supply could be at either end.
If the generator has a battery (12V or 24V or whatever) used for starting then it can be fed
Battery+ve - Relay coil - one leg of cable switch at house -0 other leg of cable - Battery -ve.

There are a very large number of relays available for any load liable to be required.
If operating from a battery then use a lower voltage relay coil plus a series resistor so that relay coil voltage will be correct when operated via wiring run and resistor.

Example only:
Battery = 24V
12V relay coil = 240 Ohms so rated coil current = I=V/R = 12/240 = 50 mA.
To operate on 24V you need to drop 12V in the cable + resistor.
Say cable resistance = 60 Ohms.   (Very thin wire :-) )
REquired resistance = 240 Ohms (so half of 24V drops across 240 Ohm relay coil and half across R + cable.
R_resistor = Rwanted - Rcable = 240 - 60 = 180 Ohms.
Use a 180 Ohm series resistor (a standard value in this case)

Answer (score 2):

If distance is about 100 meter then use RF kit.
RF(radio frequency) kit consume low power so use a cell to transmitter side and for receiver side use the generator battery. And finally use a relay instead of power switch

Answer (score 0):

There are nice little relay boxes that run on 12V that you can get on a popular online auction site. These come with a small battery operated FOB that sends a wireless signal to the relay box to operate the relay.

[image]

Wire the relay into the circuit that the key switch normally operates and connect a 12V supply. The FOB's operate on coin cells that do not need replacement very often - depends upon amount of usage.

I used something like this to provide remote control where I did not want to run special wires.

**Several notes**

1. These FOB devices use a coded transmission. The code can be changed on most devices by changing solder connections inside the FOB and relay module. FOB any Relay box codes must match to operate together.
2. Some of these operate in momentary pulse mode to only click the relay for maybe a second with each FOB button press. Others will hold the relay activated for as long as the FOB button is pressed. The operating mode on some can be selected by a solder connection inside the relay box.
3. Be aware that these use a fairly old technology that has been applied to many applications. The coded transmissions also have a limited number selections (128 to 1024 depending upon the model). These considerations mean that security is minimal and you could experience interference with other nearby devices that use similar technology.